# how to avoid importing self, intra-package relationships

Tags: python, exec, python-import, python-3.6

#### The directory structure is like so:

```
AppCenter/
main.pyw
|
|
_apps/
    __init__.py
    TabularApp.py
    UserAdministrationApp.py
    RegisterApp.py
    FnAdminApp.py
    PyUi/
```

#### The contents of `__init__.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '.')


__all__ = ['TabularApp',
           'UserAdministrationApp',
           'RegisterApp',
           'FnAdminApp']
```

#### The problems pop up:

When main.pyw tries to `from _apps import *`.
 In `UserAdministrationApp.py` i am trying to dynamically add tooltips to some `QListWidget` items like so:

```
for app in self.__APPS__:

    app_icon = str(os.path.join(app_icons, f"{app}.png")).replace('\\', '/')
    icon = QIcon(app_icon)
    if app != self.__class__:
        ttip_txt = eval(f'_apps.{app}.__doc__')
    else:
        ttip_txt = self.__doc__

    item = QListWidgetItem(icon, app)
    item.setText(app)
    item.setToolTip(ttip_txt)
    wdg.addItem(item)
```

The `self.__APPS__` is just a copy of `_apps.__all__`.
The first problem I encountered was that i would get an `AttributeError` saying `module x has no attribute y` in `ttip_txt = eval(f'_apps.{app}.__doc__')` I resolved this by `from _apps import *` in UserAdministrationApp module. At this point I had already renamed this module for testing purposes and everything worked, but when I changed the name back to `UserAdministrationApp.py` I got another `AttributeError` saying `module __apps has no attribute UserAdministrationApp`.

#### Questions

I tried reading the python import docs but nothing in it really spoke to me.
I am sensing it has something to do with the script trying to import itself.
But i am still intrigued by these questions:

- Why did the import fail in the first case, when i have `import _apps`?
- Why in the second case does it not at least see itself and then produce an `ImportError` instead of `AtributeError`?
- What is the optimal way to handle these types of situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a solution, and though i think it is a bit dirty and not in best style, it works.

#### First

remove the `from _apps import *` and just `from _apps import __all__`.

#### Then

In initialization of the main class from the module `UserAdministrationApp` `import` in a loop skipping `self.__class_.__name__`

```
    self.__APPS__ = _apps.__all__
    self.class_name = self.__class__.__name__
    for app in self.__APPS__:
        if self.class_name != app:
            exec(f'import _apps.{app}')
```

#### Finally

```
    for app in self.__APPS__:

        app_icon = str(os.path.join(app_icons, f"{app}.png")).replace('\\', '/')
        icon = QIcon(app_icon)
        if app != self.class_name:
            ttip_txt = eval(f'_apps.{app}.__doc__')
        else:
            ttip_txt = self.__doc__
```

Having found the solution, I would still like to hear why the error was in the first place, for educational purposes.
So if anybody at any time glances over this and knows how to...you are more  than welcome.